# How do I change the href destination of a link in a list using jquery?

Tags: list, jquery

I have been trying to edit links within lists to change their overall functionality, but have had no luck with changing any property of the links' functions.  The properties I have tried to change thus far are the text-decoration and the href destination.  This is my code for attempting to change the href destination.

```
$(".ms-vb2 a, .ms-vb-title a, .ms-vb-user a").each(function () {
    var itemText = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + itemText + '</a>');
});
```

The idea is that I want all of the links to hold the text of the original SharePoint list items, but to link me to something other than a list actions menu.  An additional note: I have been able to change text properties, such as font color, but not link properties, such as href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ms-vb2 a, .ms-vb-title a, .ms-vb-user a").each(function () {

    //Cache the current A tag.
    var currentA = $(this);

    //Use any one of the following to remove the old href.
    currentA.prop("href",null);
    currentA.removeAttr("href");
    currentA.attr("href","");

    //Use this to add your new href to the same link.
    currentA.attr("href","http://www.google.com");

});
```

Comment: I've had some success with this, so I'll start here and keep messing with it.  Thanks for the help!